# Laravel 5 dynamic content from selected dropdown

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, dropdown, laravel-blade

Hello I'm new to laravel I was trying to find the solution but unsuccessful.
I manage to get the selected value using ajax but I cant show results in the same view that I selected from. 
Let me explain what I want to achieve.

- User select the value(id) from dropdown (populated from DB)
- the value id need to be pass to controller get new array of a query result
- return an array to the same view with show what was selected in dropdown

Any suggestion I will appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood is , you want to populate one select box based on another select box value,

He are some best start tutorial for you,

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/using-jquery-ajax-populate-selection-list/

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial I will go through them. 
The idea is to based on selection of Dropbox to get forms that are stored in DB and generate them below dropbox.